# vim "gq}" command to re-wrap paragraph, and LaTeX

Tags: vim, latex

How can I make this command not wrap things like `\item`?

For example:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item this might be a long paragraph that spans multiple lines 
\item blah
\end{enumerate}
```

if I run "gq}" with the cursor on the first item (first letter of `this`), it produces this output:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item this might be a long 
paragraph that spans multiple 
lines \item blah \end{enumerate}
```

This is what I want:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item this might be a long 
paragraph that spans multiple 
lines 
\item blah
\end{enumerate}
```

If I can somehow get vim to recognize that the token `\item` signifies the end of a paragraph, I'm thinking it will work correctly. How would I go about doing that, though?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can do this with the 'formatlistpat' option set to include the paragraph-delimiting tags. You need to include 'n' in 'formatoptions' for that to work. See

```
:help 'formatlistpat'
:help 'formatoptions'
```

For example, with

```
:set formatlistpat=^\\s*\\\\\\(end\\\\|item\\)\\>
:set formatoptions+=n
:set textwidth=40
```

formatting your example produces this:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item this might be a long paragraph
     that spans multiple lines 
\item blah
\end{enumerate}
```

Note that the second line of the first item is indented by the length of the `\item` tag, so it's not exactly what you wanted, but it might be close enough. You might also experiment with `\ze` as mentioned in the help to see if you can get Vim to recognize the tag without indenting the subsequent lines. I didn't try that.

**Update**

The 'formatlistpat' is a little clearer, and easier to edit, if it is set using `:let` instead of `:set`.

```
:let &l:flp = '^\s*\\\(end\|item\)\>'
```

The `l:` portion specifies that it is a buffer-local setting.

**Update**

To reduce the indent down to 1 character, do this:

```
:let &l:flp = '^\s*\\\ze\(end\|item\)\>'
```

Note that if there are any white spaces before the `\item`, then the indent becomes that number + 1. I don't know if it's possible to reduce the indent down to 0 using the `\ze`.

Comment: Cool! Is there a way to only use a custom formatlistpat for specific file extensions? I feel like it may be cleaner to only recognize `\item` as a paragraph-delimiting tag in files that end with the `.tex` extension. Also, why are there so many \ characters?

Comment: `:help 'formatlistpat'` says that the option is local to buffer, so you could put that setting in ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim and use `setlocal` instead of `set` and it would affect only .tex files. The \ characters are just the way special characters have to be escaped on the rhs of a `set` command. If I did any more with that setting, I would set it using `let &flp = "stuff"` rather than `set flp=stuff`. The quoting and escaping on the rhs of a `let` is much easier. See `:help :let-&`. The branch separator is `\|`. That has to escaped for some reason as `\\|`. The `set` set requires

Comment: each of those to be escaped, so you wind up with `\\\\|`. I don't have a good explanation of why.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the formatting you've done. You used vim and the command `gq}`, right? So far I'm doing `:set tw=40` and `:set formatlistpat=^\\s*\\\\\\(end\\\\|item\\)\\>`, but it's still acting the same as before. (Also, what does the `\\>` at the end do?)

Comment: I did use vim. I happened to use gvim on Windows, but I can try again on Linux. I formatted by highlighting all the lines using `V`, then typing `gq`, but that shouldn't matter. The `\\>` is really `\>` with an extra backslash for `set`. It means end of word. Let me get on a better computer, I'll verify that setting and `gq}` and get back to you. You do have `n` in your 'formatoptions', right?

Comment: OK, I opened a new buffer, copied your text into it, copied the 'formatlist' setting from my answer above, `:set fo+=n tw=40`, moved the cursor to in front of `\begin`, and typed `gq}`. It worked just as before. I was using gvim 7.3.487 on Linux.

Comment: Thanks! The trick was `fo+=n`. (I should have looked at `:help 'formatoptions'` before testing the `formatlistpat` stuff...) It might be helpful to include `:set tw=40` and `:set fo+=n` in the snippet.

Comment: Good idea. Done.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution that works for me.
I've wrote an external script to handle the formatting of latex text (https://github.com/elmanuelito/par-latex)

Example of usage in vim:

- Select some text (e.g.  `Vj` or `ggVG`)
- type ":!par-latex"  (vim command-line looks like: `'<,'>!par-latex`)
- type enter

With default options, it will handle your example if you select the text within the itemize environment. For it to work when you select more text, you'll need to activate the option `format_inside_group` at the beginning of the script.